# Pass parameter value to SqlCommand

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I need to convert some code which passes the parameters value to SqlCommand. I can't explain this in words. so, let me take an example.

Eg:

Currently i am doing this,

```
Dim value1 As String = "Reference Value 1"
sql_command = New SqlCommand(query, Cn)
sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reference1", value1)
```

and i want to convert the last line and the resultant code will be as below

```
Dim value1 As String = "Reference Value 1"
sql_command = New SqlCommand(query, Cn)
command.Parameters.Add("@Reference1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
command.Parameters["@Reference1"].Value = value1 ;
```

I need to change similar kind of stuff in more than 400 files so is there any other way or shortcut or something like this so that i can save my time.

Also one more thing, if we implement like this then it will increase the performance?

Comment: I think there is none. How will you know the equivalent sql data type from your c# data type? I guess you need to manually update it. *..just an idea though..*

Comment: I know i need to do this manually but i just need to know is there any shortcut or something like this. and one more thing. every field is varchar in database.

Comment: Why do you think this would increase performance. And only  shortcut I would be able to think of is `ctrl+h` to replace, but thisis only going to work if all code looks the same

Comment: by default it search for the NVarchar and if you convert that then it will search into the specific type only. and for another, there are different argument so i need to do this manually. thanks to Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SqlCommand.Parameters.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the parameter, so you can combine the two lines:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Reference1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = value1;
```